# How to insert request body using BodyInserters in Spring5?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I am using Sping webflux module and create a WebClient, request uri and request body as follows:

```
// create webclient
WebClient wc3 = WebClient.builder()
                            .baseUrl("http://localhost:8080")
                            .defaultCookie("key", "val")
                            .defaultHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
                            .build();
// set uri
WebClient.RequestBodySpec uri1 = wc3.method(HttpMethod.POST).uri("/getDocs");


//  set a request body
WebClient.RequestBodySpec requestSpec1 = WebClient.create().method(HttpMethod.POST).uri("/getDocs")
                                                .body(BodyInserters.fromPublisher(Mono.just("data")), String.class);
```

and when i am setting the request body, i am getting the following compilation error:

```
Multiple markers at this line
    - Type mismatch: cannot convert from Mono<String> to P
    - The method fromPublisher(P, Class<T>) in the type BodyInserters is not applicable for the arguments 
     (Mono<String>)
```

The java editor is showing just **"Rename in file"** as the suggestion.

I am not sure if i am using the BodyInserters perfectly or not. Please suggest.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It has to be like this

```
//  set a request body
WebClient.RequestHeadersSpec<?> data = WebClient.create().method(HttpMethod.POST).uri("/getDocs")
                                                .body(BodyInserters.fromPublisher(Mono.just("data"), String.class));
```